# I don't understand level of abstraction

Tags: abstraction

I have an internship interest question that says:
"At what level of abstraction would you like to impact product development"
and I have to rank from 1 to 4 on topics like Application Layer, UI, OS, and so on. What does level of abstraction mean in this sense? I'm a student who hasn't done many independent projects except for coursework and I'm not sure how to interpret this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fancy way of asking you what type of development or design interests you the most. The term "abstraction" is referring to the idea that while ultimately computers are shuffling around a lot of 1s and 0s, these bits of data are abstracted (made user-friendly) through the use of operating systems, applications, and user interfaces, etc.

So you could say, for example, you are most interested in User Interface design ("UI"), and least interested in configuring networking and operating systems (OS). Or the other way around if that's what you want to do.

On a related note, there are "7 layers" of abstraction in the classic OSI model of communications systems, going from the hardware level to the application level, so that's probably where they got the term and they're probably using the term "abstraction" to sound fancy and high-tech. Really they're just asking if you'd prefer to intern with the graphic designers, software developers, or the network team.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ... the question is obtuse imho.

The plain&simple question is likely trying to decipher your interest:

```
Do you want to work on {application,ui,os,...,kernel} product development?
```

Comment: So is 1 max priority or least?